# Nerve damage in fingers and hands?

Tags: weightlifting

Starting about a week ago, whenever I'd come back from working out, I'd have this sensation in my right hand, especially my fingers (palm side) and not so much on the palm, and the pressure was greatest on the tips of my fingers. Weird thing was my left hand didn't have this problem. It would usually disappear when I would wake up from sleep, or after 6 hours. This would only happen on days I worked out. However, it came up again about 3 days ago, on a day where I don't workout. Ever since then, it has become permanent. I isolated the cause of the problem to be the screwing wrench thing for the barbell since it applies great pressure between my palm and fingers when i squeeze it. I, without thinking, used my left hand to squeeze it, and sure enough, now my left hand has the same problem too.

The sensation can be described as: when you wrap a rubber band around a finger and squeeze it, the part thats red and full of blood (the numbness), that's how my fingers are. When your foot falls asleep, u touch it, and you KNOW that you're touching it, but u can barely feel it. The feeling is super blunted. So my sense of touch and feeling in my finger is very blunted. I can move my fingers perfectly without problem; it's just the sense of feeling, especially on the tips.

I made a doctor's appointment, but I have to wait about 3 weeks because I wanted to go to the doctors for other things too, but should i make ASAP appointment with different doctor if this is too dangerous?

Comment: What kind of sensation? Pain? Numbness?

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD no pain, mostly numbness to feeling to my skin. I described the sensation above and compared it to rapping a rubber band around a finger with a lot of pressure

Comment: It sounds like a pinched nerve.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce how serious of an issue is it?

Comment: @Abdul Well, from my anecdotal experience when I was experiencing numb pinkies from squatting because the bar was resting too high on my back and thus too high on my spine, it eventually went away when I adjusted form. I've since moved to the low bar squat as well to completely prevent such issues. I mean, I'm not a doctor, so I can't tell you how potentially serious YOUR issue is. But the issue I experienced would cause numb pinkies and ring fingers for 2-3 days on end and typically "re-newed" each time I went to squat, until I fixed my form.

Comment: If your fingers are anything but their normal, oxygenated color, then I would definitely go to an emergency room.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce incidentally, I started noticing this issue, when I started squatting again last week. My left hand is unaffected, which made me discount the blame on squatting. So, you're saying squatting for your did something to your spine, which resulted in numbness in pinkies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you go see a doctor ASAP. When it comes to neurological issues, the faster you understand the problem and solution, the faster you can breathe easier. 
 
While finger numbness is normal, what you've described above seems very unusual and it seemed to be escalating. 
 
I would suggest seeing a specialist very soon and resolving the issue. If it happens to be no big deal, at least, you'll be at peace faster.

Comment: FWIW, there's at least one completely benign version of it. I'm prone to it and the doctor basically shrugged and said that it wasn't harmful and to not worry. My fingers (and it's just certain of my fingers) go cold and the sensation is lessened for a while. Wish I could remember the name the doctor gave it.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Alright....as long as a specialist says you're fine, that's good :).